# Crystal Report 7 installation

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there any Seagate Crystal Reports 7 in 64 bit?

I am trying to install CR7 on a Windows 7 64 bit computer.. Compatibility issue because of the bit.

I needed to install Crystal Report 7 because of a system that only runs on CR7.. Do you know any work around?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [blog](http://mitkothinks.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-install-crystal-reports-7-on.html) post out. The writer seems to have successfully done the installation. You could also always run it in XP Mode, which should be working just fine.